# How to add without null value in arraylist from resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

Im new for java, I want add only registration id in arraylist from resultset while call .I dont want add null or empty values in that list. How to do.

Here my code:
I call the method like this

```
ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
array_list = getRegId();
```

getRegId Method below:

```
public ArrayList<String> getRegId() throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();      
    try{
        Statement chkUserStmt = DataAccess.conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT REGID FROM USER ";
        ResultSet rs = chkUserStmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            array_list.add(rs.getString("REGID")); 

        }
        chkUserStmt.close(); 
    }catch (SQLException sqle) {
           // mobile = sqle.getMessage();
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            //mobile = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return array_list;
}
```

I didn't get output... Can anyone help me!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: well - what *do* you get? Did you consider filtering out empty / null values in SQL Statement (`WHERE REGID <> '' AND REGID IS NOT NULL`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude them from the query itself by adding a condition in the `where` clause:

```
String query = "SELECT regid FROM user WHERE regid IS NOT NULL";
```